# How to overcome formatted string limitations when using exec() eval() method?

Tags: python, api, code-generation

i have a problem due to the **limitation of the eval/exec** function

as exec and eval won't adapt to the correct types automatically (as we are within a formatted string) , in (a lot) of situations that require code generation, this formatted string evaluation method won't work (see example below).

so I'm asking the community if there's a smarter way to create this kind of API generation

Example:

```
# *context: writing automation using software api*
# I need to apply the dict values to the API, to do so I will use exec()

dict = { 
    "api"   : "value"
    "count" : 5
    "name" : "MyCustomName"
    "color" : [1,0,0]
}

import API 

for key,value in dict.items():
    exec(f"API.{key} = {value}") #this won't work because value type isn't supported in formatted string
```

Comment: You dont need exec for this

Comment: ah? did i miss something obvious?

Comment: There is almost *never* a case for eval. There's almost *always* another way, and unless you're doing something *very* unusual you can get rid of the "almost".

Comment: Indeed, i wish i knew setattr() sooner !

Comment: Unless your actual goal is to dynamically evaluate code, eval/exec is never the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exec` is unnecessary, just use `setattr`:

```
for key,value in dict.items():
    setattr(API, key, value)
```

Side note: don't name variables `dict`, it shadows a builtin.